# PHP : Convert DateTime String VCALENDAR accepted format

Tags: php

I have datetime string as `Tue Aug 18 2015 07:20:00 GMT 0530 (IST)` and would like to convert as `VCALENDAR` accepted format as `20150818T125000Z`.

Any assistance are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in this way:

```
$str = "Tue Aug 18 2015 07:20:00 GMT 0530 (IST)";
// remove the part after GMT
$str = substr($str,0,-11);
// create date from string
$date = date_create($str);
// IST (Indian Standard Time) = Asia/Kolkata
$zone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
// set timezone
date_timezone_set($date,$zone);
// output formatted date
$vcal = $date->format("Ymd\THis\Z");
echo $vcal;
```

Output is:

```
20150818T125000Z
```

Comment: Thanks for your short answer